# How do I get the URL of the web page a Java Applet is currently running on?

Tags: java, url, applet

I am making an applet in Java that will be embedded into a web page, but the URL of the page is dynamic. I need to be able to get the current URL of the page that the applet is running on. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: By 'dynamic' do you mean an URL with name/value pairs at the end?  Give us an example URL.

Comment: *"I need to be able to get the current URL"*  Why exactly?  What feature are you trying to implement by knowing such information?

Comment: By dynamic I just mean that it wouldn't be static - it can change. Andrew, the applet is to be embedded on a web page, and it contains a few buttons that should open a URLConnection to a specified URL, but as stated, the URL isn't static. The URL that one of the buttons opens a connection to, for example, is currentURL/someFolder/someOtherFolder/

Note that it doesn't change the current URL - it just temporarily opens a connection to another one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`getDocumentBase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase%28%29)

---

> Using getDocumentBase() actually gave me a NullPointerException..

It works fine here.  I just tested it using this code.

```
// <applet code=MyLocation width=400 height=30></applet>
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyLocation extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        add( new JLabel(getDocumentBase().toString()));
    }
}
```

To compile & run it, do the following after saving the source.

```
prompt> javac MyLocation.java
prompt> appletviewer MyLocation.java
```

The `.java` extension on the second line is no typo.  Recent versions of applet viewer will look in the specified source code for an `applet` element defined in a comment.

Comment: Thanks guys. And yes, I intend to read up on the documentation when I get some time; I can't wait for summer so I can finally have time to read through it all.

Comment: See the update.  What result do you get after saving the code and running it using the 2 commands shown?  Here I see an applet containing a file based URI that points to the source code.

Comment: I got where my error was coming from; I didn't have the getDocumentBase() inside the init method. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MasterPpv You need to read the documentation *before you start coding.* Not when summer finally comes along.

Comment: @EJP This was almost three years ago now. I know a lot better now and do tend to read up before I start, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
[YourApplet].getCodeBase();
```

This method returns you the URL object. Then you obtain what you need :)

Comment: `getCodeBase()`  That answer is wrong.  If the applet element specifies a codebase other than the current directory (which is the default if it is *not* specified), the code base will ***not*** point to the same location as the HTML (the document base).

Comment: aa okay ... so it would return some URL object but this one could point to totally different location... okay now i see the difference :) thanks :)