# How to load next panel in a frame, which is already set with a panel using setContentPanel()

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel

I've a JFrame class and two JPanel classes. At first, I want to add Panel1 when Jframe main() is invoked, and when "Next>" button in the Panel1 is clicked, want to open Panel2.

Now what I'm trying is run JFrame, which is opening Panel1 by calling jFrameObj.setContentPane(Panel1). Later my cotrol moves to Panel1 and Now how can I do setContentPane(Panel2) on the same jFrameObj ?

Is this the correct approach for my functionality? Recommend me if any other approach is there?

Comment: You may use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to accomplish this task.

Comment: Can some one tell me how to use card layout for my requirement or purpose?

Comment: Please start with the Tutorial that @Howard links to. 1+ to him.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm not using Wizards, just using only JPanels and a JFrame. Do anybody has details of using card layout only between a JFrame (one class file with main()) and set of JPanels (a class file for each JPanel) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple program illustrating the usage of a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for the required task. You might also want to have a look into this [article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/) (from 2005 so some things may have changed).

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayoutTestApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        final Container pane = getContentPane();
        final CardLayout paneLayout = new CardLayout();

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Next>>");
        panel1.add(button1);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                paneLayout.show(pane, "Card2");
            }
        });

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(new JLabel("Second Panel"));

        pane.setLayout(paneLayout);
        pane.add(panel1, "Card1");
        pane.add(panel2, "Card2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. +1  But I'm curious, why enclosed in an applet?  BTW - do you know the trick for launching applets using appletviewer direct from the source (without using an HTML)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Applet fits quite nice for me for such simple test applications. They can be launched directly in Eclipse and don't need any additional main or invokeLater...

Comment: *"They can be launched directly in Eclipse and don't need any additional main or invokeLater."* I suspect you are wrong about the `invokeLater()`, I vaguely recall seeing something at Sun that maintained that though that had been the advice, it was no longer true - both applets and frames need it.  Having said that, I often leave it out.  On a related matter, if you liked that convenience, you are going to *love* [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10066726/418556) little trick. ;)